# How to set best column width in fastest way in wxpython grid?

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, size

I have a notebook with 5 pages, grid objects on each page. Each grid has 3000 rows and 4000 columns. I add employee name and surnames in first 2 columns in each page. I want to make sure all columns are set to best size so that each name is completely visible, therefore I use `self.AutoSize()`. But it takes too long time. When I comment out `self.AutoSize()`, execution time is reduced significantly. Thus I want to use `self.SetColSize(int col, int width)` method instead. Since I know each employee names and surnames, I can set the column size to longest name/surname.

But how do I convert the name/surname length to pixels? For example, if longest surname in column is `"Rooney"`, then what should be the column size in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

The [GetTextExtent](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#GetTextExtent) should be the way to go. However I have never used it together with grid.